# How to trigger animation on the host component in angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

Let's say I have a component that I would like to animate like [that](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/global-search/overview#nbsearchcomponent) (the transition of the entire page and insertion of this another search view).

How can I do that? I have animations but I don't know how to trigger them on the component itself

Comment: What exactly is `that`, you're just linking a page without explaining what exactly is relevant on it.

Comment: @Mike S. The link has an example of a search component, once you click the search button, the entire page is animated and the search component pops up